# Using Addprefix function makes the string uncomparable to another string

Tags: string, syntax, makefile, escaping, gnu-make

So, I have the following code:

```
OBJ := $(addprefix 'obj_', $(basename $(notdir /build/common.mk)))
```

**so now OBJ1 is "obj_common"**

```
ifeq ($(OBJ),obj_common)
    @echo equal (**don't know how to format indent in this website..assume there is.**)
endif
```

**the ifeq can't compare $(OBJ) to obj_common, at least it didn't echo...**

(However, if I get rid of addprefix function as follow:)

```
OBJ := $(basename $(notdir /build/common.mk))
```

**so now OBJ1 is "common"**

```
ifeq ($(OBJ),common)
    @echo equal
endif
```

**this code would echo, which means they can compare and are equal.**

I need to reference the variable `$(OBJ_common)` (I have a big list of this kind of variable, so I can't manually input the string by hand), but now addprefix function makes this string not a string... 
Could anyone please help me resolve the issue? If my question is not clear, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the mistake is in the following statement:

> ```
> OBJ := $(addprefix 'obj_', $(basename $(notdir /build/common.mk)))
> so now OBJ1 is "obj_common"
> ```

In fact, `OBJ1` becomes `'obj'_common` because of quotes that you used in the first argument to `addprefix`.

So without the quotes it should work fine:

```
OBJ := $(addprefix obj_, $(basename $(notdir /build/common.mk)))
```

### Tip

Use [`warning` and `error`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) functions for debugging your scripts:

```
OBJ := ...
$(warning so now OBJ1 is [$(OBJ1)])
```