# makefile, what is the diff between obj_$(variable) and $(addprefix "obj_", $(variable))

Tags: debugging, syntax, makefile, gnu

As the title, in makefile GNU, what is the diff between **obj_$(variable)** and **$(addprefix "obj_", $(variable))**. I am sure there is the difference, because the first one can be compared to a string, and the latter one cannot be recognized as a string. Please let me know if I am wrong. I want to make the second one work as a string, so I can use $($(addprefix "obj_", $(variable))) as a variable (now it doesn't work).

Thank you guys.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but try leaving out the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it by yourself:

```
print_values = \
    $(warning Let the value of '$$(variable)' to be [$(variable)]) \
    $(warning then the value of obj_$$(variable) is [obj_$(variable)]) \
    $(warning $$(addprefix  "obj_", $$(variable)) is [$(addprefix "obj_", $(variable))]) \
    $(warning )

variable := foo
$(print_values)

variable := foo bar baz
$(print_values)

variable :=
variable += foo
$(print_values)
```

You will get the following output:

```
makefile:10: Let the value of '$(variable)' to be [foo]
makefile:10: then the value of obj_$(variable) is [obj_foo]
makefile:10: $(addprefix  "obj_", $(variable)) is ["obj_"foo]
makefile:10: 
makefile:13: Let the value of '$(variable)' to be [foo bar]
makefile:13: then the value of obj_$(variable) is [obj_foo bar]
makefile:13: $(addprefix  "obj_", $(variable)) is ["obj_"foo "obj_"bar]
makefile:13: 
makefile:17: Let the value of '$(variable)' to be [ foo]
makefile:17: then the value of obj_$(variable) is [obj_ foo]
makefile:17: $(addprefix  "obj_", $(variable)) is ["obj_"foo]
makefile:17:
```

P.S. As I told you in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805315/545027) to another your question, **quotes are definitely not what you want**.

Use plain `obj_`:

```
$(addprefix obj_,$(variable))
```

Instead of:

```
$(addprefix "obj_",$(variable))
```